# SSH PEM_PATH check for password prompt

Tags: ssh, bash

I am copying the public key of the pem file generated from External Box to all  EC2 instances. This prompts for password for first time
Therafter I am able to do scp to all EC2 instance without password using PEM_PATH.

After 1st run 
I am trying to check if external box is able to SSH into without password using 
below code

```
return_code=$(ssh -i $PEM_PATH $SWARM_UNAME@$SWARM_NODE)
```

But this is not returning.

PEM_PATH is the path to my pem file

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can check ssh connection via command

```
ssh -q -i $PEM_PATH $SWARM_UNAME@$SWARM_NODE exit
```

But to capture return code you should use code like this:

```
ssh -q -i $PEM_PATH $SWARM_UNAME@$SWARM_NODE exit
ERR_CODE=$?
```

and in variable `ERR_CODE` you will have exit code of script

Comment: @Zaks, do you get any errors, messages? And what is the content of variable `ERR_CODE`? Have you try to remove `-q` and check?